# Resharper (or Visual Studio) shortcut to cascade changes to a constructor

Tags: resharper

Here is a common refactoring that I don't believe I have seen a shortcut for:

Imagine we have a base class with a number of inheriting subclasses. The base classes uses constructor injection to accept a number of services:

```
class FooBase
{
    private IMyService _myService;
    private IMyOtherService _myOtherService;

    public FooBase(IMyService myService, IMyOtherService _myOtherService)
    {
         _myService = myService;
         _myOtherService = myOtherService;
    }
}

class FooConcrete : FooBase
{
    public FooConcrete(IMyService myService, IMyOtherService _myOtherService)
        base(myService, myOtherService)
    {
    }
}
```

Notice how FooConcrete has to call the constructor of its base class, FooBase.

Now, what happens if I want to add another service to FooBase? I can quickly initialize the new private field from FooBase's constructor. But I still have to go around and manually update every subclass that inherits from FooBase. This can be a hassle if there are lots of inheriting classes.

Is there a shortcut, or perhaps a trick that I can use, to quickly update all the subclasses' constructors as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I asked this question Resharper have now added support as part of the [Change Signature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html) feature.

For example, to add a parameter to a constructor in the base class, use the following method:

1. Right click on the constructor you want to change, select Refactor->Change Signature.
2. Make the changes you require and click Next. Select "Resolve with call tree" and click Next.
3. Your change will be made, and a window will open somewhere in Visual Studio titled "Refactoring - Change signature". A list of inheriting classes will be shown in this window.
4. Double click on each of the classes and choose the "Create parameter x in constructor y"

Answer (score 1):

Build, then Fix compilation errors.

ReSharper has no tool for this, including AFAIK in ReSharper 6, which got launched today.

Answer (score 1):

### Parameter class by ReSharper refactoring

If you know that constructors can change through the lifetime you could create a parameter class like:

```
class FooInfo
{
    IMyService MyService {get; set;}
    IMyOtherService MyOtherService {get; set;}
}
```

and can pass such an object to constructor, i.e:

```
class FooBase
{
    private FooInfo _fooInfo;

    public FooBase(FooInfo fooInfo)
    {
         _fooInfo= fooInfo;
    }
}

class FooConcrete : FooBase
{
    public FooConcrete(FooInfo fooInfo)
        base(fooInfo)
    {
    }
}
```

Then if you need a new parameter you just add it to `FooInfo` class. Changes in subclasses are not needed.

**ReSharper has a refactoring** for generating such a parameter class from constructor parameters:
Place cursor on constructor name in code file and
press ***Ctrl+Shift+R*** and
select ***Extract Class From Parameters...***.

Comment: Yes that is an option sometimes, but not really if you are using an DI framework that relies on constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

### *Default Value* in *Change Signature*

The best way I know is to add new service parameter to `FooBase` constructor by ***Change Signature*** (*Ctrl+R,S*) with a proper parameter name as **default value**, e.g. `yetAnotherService`.

After that you have indeed errors in `base` calls in all sub class constructors. But you can fix every error by only 3 key strokes:
- go to error by ***Alt+Shift+Page Down***,
- open context menu by ***Alt+Enter***,
- select first option (*Create parameter 'yetAnotherService' in containing constructor*) by ***Enter***.

Ok you still have many key strokes. But it's the fastest way (with ReSharper 5.1.3) I know.